# Freeze table header while allowing dynamic widths

Tags: html, css, html-table

The solutions I've seen for freezing a table header row is by creating another table with just the header, making the first table's header hidden. This works only if the widths are pre set. But I want my table's columns to be sized according to their contents. I also want the table to not have a fixed height, because I want to use it across devices, and want to use all available space (minus reserved one for a header)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach to this is similar to your other question. Except in this case, the `<tbody>` is the viewport, and we'll need to give its rows `display: table`, so their widths can be manually set.

---

I've added some JS to essentially clone the top rows with the most content and append them as visually hidden rows to `<thead>` to help get it to the right width dynamically. I've also re-tuned the CSS. Note layout still breaks if `<th>` content is longer than `<td>` content.

```js
$(function() {

  var $table = $('table');

  var $body = $table.find('tbody');
  var rowTexts = $body.find('tr').map(function() {
    return $(this).text().trim();
  }).toArray().sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a.length > b.length) ? -1 : (a.length < b.length) ? 1 : 0;
  });

  if (rowTexts.length > 5) {
    rowTexts = rowTexts.slice(0, 5);
  }

  var $head = $table.find('thead');
  rowTexts.forEach(function(text) {
    var $hiddenRow = $body.find('tr:contains(' + text + ')').clone().addClass('hidden');
    $head.append($hiddenRow);
  });


});
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 44px;
  width: 100%;
}
td,
th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  height: 44px;
  line-height: 44px;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
tr.hidden td {
  border: 0;
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
thead {
  display: table;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
thead tr:not(.hidden) {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Key</th>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Key that's longer than usual</td>
      <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Key</td>
      <td>Value that's longer than usual</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Key</td>
      <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Key</td>
      <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Key</td>
      <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Key</td>
      <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Key</td>
      <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Key</td>
      <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Key</td>
      <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Key</td>
      <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Key</td>
      <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last Key</td>
      <td>Last Value</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It looks like if a cell has a longer content the rest will not be sized accordingly

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there's a way to implement this with one table and without using JS to sync the `<thead>`, but using any JS would be slow as you get more rows. I don't see many other options besides writing a full-blown data-grid JS component.

Comment: I've revised the solution. Not perfect, but it should get you pretty far. Feel free to port the JS to whatever framework you're using. I'd suggest using a MutationObserver on the table to know when to re-run the JS.