# How can I create a fixed header?

Tags: html, css

I want a header that is displayed at the top where the content always appears below it. The solutions that I've seen use position:fixed which means that if the content (a long table) is scrolled, it appears below the header.

I want the content to not have a fixed height, since I want to use on different devices.

Comment: Use  `position:fixed `

Comment: Well, I don't see any problem. You already resolved your question. position: fixed is what you need. You just said it.

Comment: You are on the right path, you need to give it the desired height as well, and ajdust the z-index, to ensure it will be on the top, always. z-index is integer property and has no measurement unit. You can set the content container height to fit it against the header and you can use overflow property to bypass the page scrolls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. Basically you need to limit `<body>` height and wrap a viewport `<div>` around your `<table>` that's offset and stretched to screen height using `position: absolute`, and it should take scrolling away from body by having its own `overflow: auto`. If you create this viewport you don't even need `position: fixed` on the header.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
header {
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 44px;
  line-height: 44px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
.viewport {
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 44px;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,
td {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  height: 44px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>Header Title</header>
<div class="viewport">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Content Table</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Some key:</td>
        <td>some value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some key:</td>
        <td>some value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some key:</td>
        <td>some value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some key:</td>
        <td>some value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some key:</td>
        <td>some value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some key:</td>
        <td>some value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some key:</td>
        <td>some value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some key:</td>
        <td>some value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some key:</td>
        <td>some value</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Some key:</td>
        <td>some value</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: did the job!. can you also take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28513718/freeze-table-header-while-allowing-dynamic-widths-in-angular?

Comment: One question: I don't have the left margin (or padding) that I used to have (i'm using bootstrap and both header and viewport are in a .container-fluid and marked with .row

Comment: Bootstrap's `.container-fluid` uses the [`.container-fixed` mixin](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/49519e981614fb8e0c4fabcbb0a632db292c2b3c/less/mixins/grid.less) which looks like it does some additional styling that's not related and possibly conflicting. The same probably also applies to `.row` which uses the `.make-row` mixin, also in that file. I do not suggest using either class. If you need clearfix you can use `&:extend(.clearfix)` in your less or add it to the header and viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I don't recommend using fixed positioning as it's not stable on some old devices and platforms,the fixed value is the most later supported value in position, so i recommend you using absolute positioning,you can split your html page into two divs, one for header and one for content,and set two divs to absolute positioning but in case of content set overflow to auto.
Here is a sample code

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            </head>
            <body>
             <div style="position:absolute;height:20%;width:100%;background-color:red">
             Fixed header with height 20%
             </div>
             <div style="position:absolute;top:20%;height:80%;width:100%;background-color:green;overflow:auto">
             Your scrollable content here
            </div>
             </div>
             </body>
            </html>
```

you can adjust your header in percentage or absolute values